# which is better way to fetch category products?

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

I am writing **REST api to retrieve category** (featured products) which is on homepage. I am using `homepage/featured` as endpoint. Now in `_retrieveCollection()` method of `v1.php` I am using following code.

```
  $maincategory = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/category' )->load ( 191 )//cateogy id
                  ->getProductCollection ()
                  ->addAttributeToSelect ( '*' );
```

Is this a hard coding retrieving categories by their id? we can retrieve like this also

```
  $category  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
             ->addFieldToFilter('name',array('eq'=>'Featured Products'));

  $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getFirstItem()
            ->getId())->getProductCollection();
```

So which is the **better way to fetch products from category** and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Step 1 You are getting category by category which is hard coded. But in Step 2 you trying to retrieve the category id by name which is also Hard coded and for this you have to load collection 2 times and if any time you want to change the category name, you won't.

So the better way is Make a admin configuration like **Featured Category ID** to store category ID from admin. and get that value by using `getStoreConfig()` method.

This will give you full dynamic feature in Step 1 and it will be faster also.

Comment: did you mean, to make new tab/section Featured category and manually save category id in the field of that section/tab, and then retrieve from them?

Comment: @Shrikant Yes, Thats same I am recommending.